# Using a image files for menu text

Tags: html, css, image

I have one image that is a background image, it stretches the full page

it also has a menu bar it in (with out the text )

I have four text image files (about, home, etc)

I want to place them on top of  the background image

but when I do, they resize out of the menu bar if I am not in full screen

here is what I have so far if there is a easier way to do this please let me know

```
    <html>
    <style> 
     body
     { 
        background: url("http://imageshack.us/a/img84/4772/backgroundnomenutext.png")
                    no-repeat scroll;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        min-height: 700px; 
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div style="position:relative">

      <a href="http://www.google.com">
       <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img835/7200/homefw.png"

        style = "position:absolute; top: 160px; left: 100px;"/>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you missed the closing `a` tag.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give top and left values in percentages instead of pixels to the `img` tag which will make them (`div` and `img`) look attached.

```
img
{
  top : /* In percentages */
  left: /* In percentages */
}
```

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtKWa/)**

**or else** go with fixed width and heights

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MtKWa/2/)

```
<html>
 <head>
   <style> 
     body
     { 
        background: url("http://imageshack.us/a/img84/4772/backgroundnomenutext.png")
                no-repeat scroll;
        background-size: 1024px 768px;
        min-height: 700px; 
        max-width:1024px;
        min-width:700px;
     }
     img 
     { 
        position:absolute; 
        top: 180px; 
        left: 300px; 
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

 <div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com"  >
       <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img835/7200/homefw.png"/>
    </a>
 </div>

</body>
</html>​
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: could you be a little more specific i just tried it and it was not working

Comment: @JackBlack First of all, did you gave closing tag to `a` as I mentioned before? If not then please give it and try again..

Comment: Hey @JackBlack you are giving `position:absolute` to the `img` tag.. so the percentage value will not effect it.. try with `position:relative` instead.

Comment: the code i postedd up top works  the menu image is in place its only if i minmize the browser in any way the menu image will not  stay with the background ,sorry if im not explaining it very well

Comment: @JackBlack check this [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MtKWa/). and also see my update post..

Comment: ok i got it to work with that one text home image , but i want to add the rest of the links but im having problems with the img placement you have IMG {CORDS} when i duplicate it i run into problems

Comment: to simplify everything i just went with                              <a href="http://www.mma.tv"><IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:205px; LEFT:755px;" SRC="http://imageshack.us/a/img266/3628/abouttext.png">

Comment: @JackBlack It seems you are giving same `TOP` and `Left` values to all the Image menus.. Variate the `Left` value for adjustment. and give Unique `class` names to each image. and call the properties by using those `class` names instead of calling as `img{cords}` call `img1{cords}` , `img2{cords}`, etc.. where `img1`, `img2` are the  `class` names of the image menus..